# How can I have a list as a plot legend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following code:

```
A = Table[i,{i,0.1,2,0.25}];
y = A*Cos[x]
Plot[y, {x, 0, Pi}]
```

And I want to label each value of `A*Cos[x]` with its respective value from `A`. How can I do that?, i.e., produce a legend that labels every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `PlotLabels`:

```
A = Table[i, {i, 0.1, 2, 0.25}];
y = A*Cos[x]
Plot[y
 , {x, 0, Pi}
 , PlotLabels -> A
 (*,PlotLegends\[Rule]Placed[
 LineLegend[Automatic,A
 ,LegendMarkerSize\[Rule]15
 ,LegendLabel\[Rule]"A"
 ,LegendFunction\[Rule](Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 5] & )
 ]
 ,After]*)
 
 ]
```

[image]

You can uncomment the `PlotLegends` statement to see if you like that better.

---

**EDIT**

```
Plot[y
 , {x, 0, Pi}
 , PlotLabels -> A
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[(Directive @@ {Dashed, #} & /@ (ColorData[97][#] & /@ 
        Range@Length@A)), A
    , LegendMarkerSize -> 25
    , Spacings -> 0.05
    , LegendLabel -> "A"
    , LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 5, 
        RoundingRadius -> 5] & )
    ]
   , After]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is along the right lines, I was hoping to have a legend which has a dash of the line colour next to the value if that makes sense?

Comment: Please see the edit. This, however, is a hack. If you want dashed `LineLegend` markers, then the better way is to have dashed `PlotStyle` associated with the curves in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the option `BaseStyle -> Dashed` in `LineLegend`:

```
a = Table[i, {i, 0.1, 2, 0.25}]; y = a*Cos[x];

Plot[y, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[Automatic, a, LegendLabel -> "a",
   BaseStyle -> Dashed, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}]]
```

[image]